# State restriction

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have some items that we are not allowed to send to California, how can I restrict people who have "CA" in their address, Woocomerce cart? I have this code but for some reason, it doesn't work

```
// REMOVE ITEMS THAT CAN'T SHIP TO CALIFORNIA/INTERNATIONAL
if( !empty($shipping_state) && $shipping_state == 'CA'){

    $removed_item = false;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        if ( has_term('not-carb-compliant-cant-ship-to-california', 'product_tag', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {

            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
            $removed_an_item = true;

        }
    }
    
    if ( $removed_an_item ) {
        $notice = 'This tem is not currently available in your region and has been removed from your cart.';
        wc_print_notice( $notice , 'error' );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: looks like you have two spellings: `$removed_item` and `$removed_an_item`. is that intentional?

Comment: While adding to the cart, the shipping_state will not be available. You can remove from cart page or checkout page based on state filled

Comment: As mentioned unless its logged in customer with saved address to compare you can compare products in cart (if option is available to add address) and checkout. Another option is to ask for location when user visit your website and even hide products that are restricted.